# Do something while waiting for a blocking action

Tags: lua, curses

I'm trying to write a curses program in Lua (mostly for ease of development before porting it to C).  It needs to be constantly ready for the user to send commands, but I also want it to be able to act on other signals, like the expiration of timers. Example uses for this might be blinking indicators, nagging the user if they take too long, and printing messages recieved over a network.

When I call `curses.getch()`, the program waits for it to return data before running the next instruction. If any other event occurs before a key is pressed, the script will not be able to react to it unless something else is done to change that.

I tried using `curses.halfdelay()` to make `curses.getch()` exit after a short period of time so that something else could be done before calling it again, but it caused strange errors. I also considered learning to use pthreads, but I don't know where to begin. I am running Linux, and I don't mind if the solution doesn't work on Windows (since I'm already using curses).

EDIT: I might have mislead people by providing so many curses-related details, but I would really prefer a more general solution that can work with other blocking operations.

Comment: Which luacurses are you using? This library seems very old. Are you building it against a modern ncurses dll?

Comment: @Schollii Why would I be building it against a DLL when I'm running Linux and don't care about Windows? That issue aside, I don't honestly know exactly what version I'm using; it's in the Ubuntu repositories and only supports Lua 5.1.

Comment: The distinction is clearly irrelevant in this context

Comment: @Scollii What distinction?

Answer (score 2):

`halfdelay()` and (more commonly) `nodelay()` are the correct solutions, in the curses space. I can assure you that they do work in the general case. You'll have to be more specific about your "strange errors".

Meanwhile, although it's not a pure curses solution (and won't work with PDCurses), people sometimes use `select()` in this situation, to wait on input from *either* curses or a network socket.

Comment: `nodelay()` isn't provided by LuaCurses (or, seemingly, by ncurses), I don't know what you mean by `select()` (Lua's `select()` function certainly doesn't seem applicable here), and `halfdelay()` isn't an ideal solution even if I can make it work. The errors I get from it seem to be related to the binding's handling of timer expiration.